# Java IRS Tax Calculation/if Else statements/Married or single

Tags: java, string, if-statement, math, java.util.scanner

I've been tasked with creating a small IRS makeshift tax calculator.
The assignments objectives to be completed are:

Write a class that
prompts the user for the following information:

Filing status: Single or Married (entered as 1 for Single and 2 for Married)

Taxable income

Calculates and prints:

Filing status

Taxable income

Federal tax

I'm supposed to have specific calculations for each of the parameters, which include 0 to 27050, 27050 to 65500, and so on, which are included in the code.
the real problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the numbers to actually show up.

my code is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class P4_Icel_Murad_IRS
    {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.printf("Enter Marital Status: (Single = 1, Married = 2):");
            int relation = in.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Enter taxable income:");
            int tax = in.nextInt();
            if (relation == 1){
                String status = "Single";
                if (tax <= 27050){
                    double tax2 = tax - 0.0;
                    double tax3 = (tax2 * 0.15);
                    System.out.printf(status,tax,tax3);
                }else if (27050 < tax && tax >= 65550){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 27050.0)* 0.275;
                    double tax3 = 4057.5 + tax2;
                }else if (65550 < tax && tax <= 136750){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 65550.0) * 0.305;
                    double tax3 = 14645.0 + tax2;
                }else if (136750 < tax && tax <= 297350){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 136750.0 - tax) * 0.355;
                    double tax3 = 36361.00 + tax2;
                }else if (297350 < tax && tax <= 1e100){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 297350) * 0.391;
                    double tax3 = 93374.0 + tax2;
                }
            }
                if (relation == 2){
                String status = "Married";
                if (tax <= 27050){
                    double tax2 = tax - 0.0;
                    double tax3 = (tax2 * 0.15);
                    System.out.printf(status,tax,tax3);
                }else if (27050 < tax && tax >= 65550){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 27050.0)* 0.275;
                    double tax3 = 4057.5 + tax2;
                }else if (65550 < tax && tax <= 136750){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 65550.0) * 0.305;
                    double tax3 = 14645.0 + tax2;
                }else if (136750 < tax && tax <= 297350){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 136750.0 - tax) * 0.355;
                    double tax3 = 36361.00 + tax2;
                }else if (297350 < tax && tax <= 1e100){
                    double tax2 = (tax - 297350) * 0.391;
                    double tax3 = 93374.0 + tax2;
                }
            }    

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variables
    tax2
    tax3
locally in the individual if blocks.

You print in one of those blocks but not all of them.

Move the declaration of them right under

```
int tax = in.nextInt();
double tax2 = 0;
double tax3 = 0;
```

and then print out their values at the end of all of your logic.

Comment: but now it says that tax2 and tax3 are already declared when i try to do the calculations

Comment: You only need to use the keyword `double` once.